# how to add value in existing .txt file when hit radio

Tags: php, arrays, radio-button

For a simple voting system i use a .txt file in which the values are stored.

This is the array of options:

```
$quickpolloptions = ['Mozilla', 'Chrome', 'Opera', 'IE', 'Safari'];
```

This is the form:

```
<form method="post" id="quickpoll">
 <table>
     <?php

    foreach ($quickpolloptions as $key => $value) {

          echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>";
                    echo "<label>$value</label>";
         echo "</td>";
         echo "<td>";
                    echo "<input type='radio' name='radiovote' value='$key'><br>";
         echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>"; 
        }

     ?>
 </table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

This is how i try to add the values in the .txt file (vote_result.txt)

```
$result_file = "data/vote_result.txt";


if (file_exists($result_file)) {
   $results = explode(',', file_get_contents('vote_result.txt'));
} else {
   // start with zeros if you don't have a file yet
   $results = array_fill(0, count($quickpolloptions), 0);
}
if (isset($_POST['radiovote'])) {
   $results[$_POST['radiovote']]++;
   file_put_contents('data/vote_result.txt', implode(',', $results));
}
```

per example: when choosing the second radio, the content of vote_result.txt looks like this: `0,1,0,0,0` This is correct. But when i vote again, lets say i chosse the 3rd radio, he overwrites the .txt file and creates this: `,1`. And it should be this: `0,1,1,0,0`

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Try cast number in array to INTEGER
Increment strings value might not work correctly.

Comment: solution found, was a typo: instead of this: `$results = explode(',', file_get_contents('data/vote_result.txt'));` i had this: `$results = explode(',', file_get_contents('vote_result.txt'));` I forgot the folder `data` in front of it

Answer (score 0):

personally I would use serialize / unserialize for such tasks. You can save an array into a txt file and read it back + change it whenever you like, example:

```
<?php

//initial array for a new file:
$quickpolloptions = [
    'Mozilla' => 0,
    'Chrome' => 0,
    'Opera' => 0,
    'IE' => 0,
    'Safari' => 0
];

$votefile =  "votes.txt";

//init the file:
if(!file_exists($votefile)){
    file_put_contents($votefile, serialize($quickpolloptions));
}

//read the file and convert it back to an array:
$data = unserialize(file_get_contents($votefile));

//example of adding a vote for Mozilla:
$data['Mozilla']++;

//save back the file:
file_put_contents($votefile, serialize($data));

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code gives same output as you want.......

```
 <?php
    $quickpolloptions = ['Mozilla', 'Chrome', 'Opera', 'IE', 'Safari'];
    $result_file = "vote_result.txt";
    if (file_exists($result_file)) {
       $results = explode(',', file_get_contents('vote_result.txt'));
    } else {
       // start with zeros if you don't have a file yet
       $results = array_fill(0, count($quickpolloptions), 0);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['radiovote'])) {
       $results[$_POST['radiovote']]++;
       file_put_contents('vote_result.txt', implode(',', $results));
    }

    ?>
    <form method="post" id="quickpoll">
     <table>
         <?php


        foreach ($quickpolloptions as $key => $value) {

              echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td>";
                        echo "<label>$value</label>";
             echo "</td>";
             echo "<td>";
                        echo "<input type='radio' name='radiovote' value='$key'><br>";
             echo "</td>";
          echo "</tr>"; 
            }

         ?>
     </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form
```